# Way to avoid duplicate entries in Many to Many relationship Join

Tags: sql-server, join, duplicates, many-to-many

I've been browsing for a while but still can't get a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to join two tables, the leads and orders table.

They both contain a unique house number.

The issue is that the leads table will have the unique house number multiple times. The unique house can be a lead multiple times.

Additionally, the orders table also can have the unique house number multiple times if that specific house places more than one order.

So a standard join on the house number will create duplicate entries.

I've tried a few things such as using min or using a row rank but have not been able to resolve this.

I need one match from the order table to join to one match in the lead table. 
This also needs to be the correct match (most likely closest in date).

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Tag your query with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.  (3) Explain the logic you want to implement -- which lead should be attached to which order, for instance.

Comment: So you are looking for the mos recent lead for each address that panned out?   Knowing what db engine you are targeting would help.   You might also show what you tried, and why that wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your backend language for example php something like this

```
    if (!$cart->items->contains($newItem->id)) {
        $cart->items()->save($newItem);
    }
```